# How to display a Bootstrap alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I''m trying to add [Bootstrap Alerts](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/alerts/), but I can't get them to be shown programmatically.

This is the HTML part:

```
<div
  class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show"
  role="alert"
  id="accepted-meal-alert">
  <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
  <p>Genial que te haya gustado la idea!</p>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#accepted-meal-alert {
  display: none;
}
```

And the JavaScript. I'm trying to use jQuery to toggle the `div`'s visibility:

```
function acceptOrGetAnotherMeal(acceptOrReject) {
  if (acceptOrReject == 'accept-btn') {
    showMealAccepted();
  } else {
    const alternativeTextPrefix = 'Entonces pidamos';
    let mealType = $("input[name='categorias']:checked").val();
    console.log(`mealType: ${mealType}`);
    getFromEndpoint(mealType, alternativeTextPrefix);
  }
}

function showMealAccepted() {
  console.log('showMealAccepted');
  $('#accepted-meal-alert').show();             // `toggle` didn't work as well.
  // $('#accepted-meal-alert').css({
  //   display: 'block',
  // });
  $('#accept-btn').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#reject-btn').prop('disabled', true);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.categorias').click(function () {
    let endpoint = $(this).attr('id');
    getFromEndpoint(endpoint, defaultTextPrefix);
  });
  $('.accept-reject-btn').click(function () {
    let acceptOrReject = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('Clicked categories with value: ' + acceptOrReject);
    acceptOrGetAnotherMeal(acceptOrReject);
  });
  $('.alert .close').click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

If this makes any difference, I'm serving this files from a Sinatra public folder.

Comment: While you may be using Sinatra, this isn't a Sinatra programming question, and shouldn't be tagged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First please check if the JavaScript is even being loaded by placing a log statement then see if the `'.accept-reject-btn'` is being triggered for the `click` event.

Try the following JavaScript:

```js
function acceptOrGetAnotherMeal(acceptOrReject) {
    if (acceptOrReject == 'accept-btn') {
        console.log( 'Meal accepted.' );
        showMealAccepted();
    } else {
        console.log( 'Meal rejected!' );
        alert( 'Meal rejected!' );
    }
    $('#accept-btn').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#reject-btn').prop('disabled', true);
}

function showMealAccepted() {
    console.log( 'showing meal accepted...' );

    $('#accepted-meal-alert').show();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.accept-reject-btn', function () {
        console.log( 'Clicked accept-reject button...' );

        let acceptOrReject = $(this).attr('id');
        acceptOrGetAnotherMeal(acceptOrReject);
    });
    $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.alert .close', function (e) {
        $(this).parent().hide();
    });
    $( document.body ).on( 'click', '.reset', function() {
        $('#accept-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#reject-btn').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#accepted-meal-alert').hide();
        console.clear();
    });
});
```

```css
#accepted-meal-alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div
  class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show"
  role="alert"
  id="accepted-meal-alert">
  <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
  <p>Genial que te haya gustado la idea!</p>
</div>

<button class="accept-reject-btn" id="accept-btn">Accept</button>
<button class="accept-reject-btn" id="reject-btn">Reject</button>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer
Looks like the click is being captured:
```
Clicked accept-reject button...
ajax.js:18 Meal accepted.
ajax.js:29 showing meal accepted...
```
but still I don't get my `div`. Maybe there's some problem with the rest of my CSS.

Comment: There was a problem with Bootstrap's version, I was using `3.3.7`. Switching to `4.0.0` made it work. Thanks for your answer!